# Azure Logic App: Azure DevOps "When A Work Item Is Closed" trigger not firing at times

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-logic-apps

I have automated some processes for when work items are closed in Azure DevOps (Boards) but on occasion the Azure Logic App is not triggered. I know this cause I have a different logic app that checks the counts between closed work items and my data warehouse and the newly closed work item is missing. I have check and the Logic App was just never triggered. There is nothing for that day the work item was closed. If I were to update the work item from closed to not closed (save) then back to closed (save) the Logic App is triggered fine. Has anyone else run into this? Is this a flaw in the Azure DevOps or Azure Logic App or Azure itself where it hiccups and just doesn't fire the event or see an event has been fired? I would expect this to be process to be seamless and work 100% of the time.

Question update:
I have several Azure Logic Apps that use the Azure Devops "When A Work Item Is Closed" Trigger connector. Several because we have different Project Names and Types I want to trigger the "When A Work Item Is Closed" event. The recurrence of the logic apps was every 3 minutes but I have since updated them to be every 1 hour. A handful of the logic apps are again failing on what would be the recurrence trigger time. And it continually fails every hour thereafter.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko39d.png)

When reviewing the Output links of the failure the message states "BadGateway", InnerError "500", and Error Message "Unknown error occurred"

This is happening with a few of the logic apps. All my logics apps are in the same subscription and the same resource group using the same API Connection and SQL Database connections.

Comment: This just happened again several times last night where it seems like the ADO DevOps "When a work item is closed" was not triggered for multiple logic apps in multiple ADO projects. This is frustrating as if this is not fired consistently it is causing missing data in my data warehouse.

Comment: The error that is happening is that in the Trigger History tab for the Logic Apps it was showing Failed. The Error that was happening was stating "Bad Gateway". I have several Logic Apps that are configured the same way, using the same API Connections, SQL Database and Storage account. The only different is the Logic Apps point to a different ADO DevOps project. Most of my Logic Apps are running as expected, a few are failing on the Triggering event.

Comment: when asking a question on this site, try to provide details that would allow others to help you. For example, you've provided no details on how the trigger is setup.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - as was my first time posting a question here. I did mention in the title the "When a work item is closed" trigger. My Azure logic apps are all configured for ADO DevOps "When a work item is closed" for several different ADO DevOps projects and work item types. So I have several logic apps that are basically the same except for the Occurrence trigger connector. So to have most of them work (being triggered successfully) and a handful fail (Trigger History showing Failed) was what I was trying to determine. All logic apps are in the same subscription and resource group

Comment: After I have answered my question, one of my logic apps is failing again with the BadGateway error. I see this in the Trigger History of my Logic App and it happens every 3 minutes when my logic apps is configured to run.

"message": "BadGateway",
            "innerError": {
                "status": 500,

Comment: Rather than adding details in the comments, use the [edit] link below the question and add it there.  If you add sufficient details, your question can also be re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my logic app, and re-deployed it and the Logic App is executing as expected and the Trigger history (where it was showing Failed previously) shows as either Skipped (nothing to do) or Succeeded.

Strange that only a handful of my Logic Apps were failing, but this fixed my issue at this time.